# Whether PXC supports OnlineDDL

Tags: ddl, percona-xtradb-cluster

I want to know PXC's support for OnlineDDL. ChatGPT and some information on the network tell me that it can be supported, but when I actually tested ALGORITHM=INPLAC didn't take effect and LOCK=NONE error was reported: LOCK=NONE is not supported for this operation. Try LOCK=SHARED. Therefore, can OnlineDDL be used on PXC, if so, how to use it specifically, and what version PXC involves?

In addition, I want to implement DDL without locking tables on PXC, so that my nodes can read and write normally, what else besides PT tool

The TOI and RSU policies were used to perform DDL operations on node 1 and read and write operations on the three nodes respectively. The read operation was normal, but the write operation was blocked